# Can I apply for a student visa in Spain once I enter the Schengen as a visa-free traveler?

Tags: visa, student-visa, schengen, spain, language-course

I'm considering learning Spanish in a language school in Spain, but it would be after I entered the Schengen area for 90-days visa-free and stayed for a while.

So for example:

- Enter the Schengen on 2019-03-01
- Travel there until 2019-05-25
- Move to Spain and start to attend school on 2019-05-26

However, I would like to apply for the visa within the Schengen for the sake of cost and time savings.

In this case,

- Can I apply for the visa once I enter the Schengen as a visa-free traveler?
- If yes, can I apply from other countries such as France?
- If I can apply only in Spain, how many days will it take and what happens if the visa issuing date surpasses the 90 days limit?

This question is about the visa-free traveler and I'm a non-EU citizen.

Comment: Spain may require the visa application to be submitted in your country of residence.